# Not able to display google maps on VS 2015 using angular 2

Tags: google-maps, angular, visual-studio-2015

this is my component:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
selector: 'my-app',
styles: [`.sebm-google-map-container {
 height: 300px;}`],
template: `<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
 </sebm-google-map>`})
```

just a simple example to display the map. But all this does is display the content in the (my-app) tag.

and the module is :

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
@NgModule({
imports: [
    .
    .
    .
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
        apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY'
    })
],
```

the value of lat and lang i'm getting from AppComponent.

```
export class AppComponent {
title: string = 'My first angular2-google-maps project';
lat: number = 51.678418;
lng: number = 7.809007;}
```

I have been successful in implementing this same code using console(angular2 cli) but when I tried this using Visual Studio 2015 it is not displaying the maps. To be specific it only shows the content in the anchor tag in index.html.

plus I would to mention I am to able to run angular2 Quickstart on VS 2015.

If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong or have some suggestion it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this was just downgrading the version of angular2-google-maps in project.json from 0.17.0 to 0.16.0.